# Converting xml request to json request with duplicate node names

Tags: javascript, json

I trying to push data to a 3rd party webservice, specifically converting the xml request to a json one (for use with node soap).

Here is an example of the raw xml request that works fine:

```
<EformData>
            <EformFields>
               <FieldName>txt_customername</FieldName>
               <FieldValue>Scott</FieldValue>
            </EformFields>
            <EformFields>
               <FieldName>txt_organisation</FieldName>
               <FieldValue>My Orginisation</FieldValue>
            </EformFields>
            <EformFields>
               <FieldName>txt_address</FieldName>
               <FieldValue>My Address</FieldValue>
            </EformFields>
            <EformFields>
               <FieldName>txt_telnumber</FieldName>
               <FieldValue>123456</FieldValue>
            </EformFields>
</EformData>
```

The problem i'm having is trying to convert these duplicate nodes into an object, the new object data is being overwritten with the last request.

Here's what i have so far:

```
var formValues = {
    "txt_customername": "Scott",
    "txt_organisation": "My Orginisation",
    "txt_address": "My Address",
    "txt_telnumber": "123456"
}

// Container
var EformData = { 
        "EformFields": {
        }  
};

// populate the object
for (var key in formValues) {            
    EformData.EformFields.FieldName = [key];
    EformData.EformFields.FieldValue = formValues[key];
}
```

As you can see below, only the last request is stored in the object, the others are overwritten:

```
 <EformData>
    <EformFields>
    <FieldName>txt_telnumber</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>123456</FieldValue>
    </EformFields>
</EformData>
```

Is it possible to build an object in such a way to match the orginal duplicate xml node data?

Comment: The data structure of your json should be that `EformData` has an array of `EformFields` objects, which has the properties of `FieldName` and `FieldValue`.

Comment: @junkangli thanks, using an array now works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure of your json should be that `EformData` has an array of `EformFields` objects, which has the properties of `FieldName` and `FieldValue`.

```
var formValues = {
    "txt_customername": "Scott",
    "txt_organisation": "My Orginisation",
    "txt_address": "My Address",
    "txt_telnumber": "123456"
}

// Container
var EformData = { 
    "EformFields": []  
};

// populate the object
for (var key in formValues) {            
    EformData.EformFields.push({
        "FieldName": key,
        "FieldValue": formValues[key]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your array, only 0th index is populated always and hence it is overrided when on the next iteration add an index for the array iteration as follows

```
// Container
var EformData = { 
    "EformFields": [
    ] 
};

// populate the object
int i=0;
for (key in formValues) {            
    EformData.EformFields[i].FieldName = [key];
    EformData.EformFields[i].FieldValue = formValues[key];
    i++;
}
```